# Using LookupRows to retrieve from synchronized data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I'm having trouble with the ampscript LookupRows to grab data from a synchronized data extension.  Here is what I have so far:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @first

set @rows = LookupRows("Contacts","FirstName", @first)
set @row = Row(@rows, 1)

]%%


%%=ProperCase(@first)=%%
```

In this case I'd like to display the First Name which exists in the Contacts synchronized data extension but I am missing a piece of the puzzle.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what [Eduardo](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7711/eduardo-arias) mentioned, you're missing a value to use to retrieve the row from your Data Extension.

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @contactID, @first

set @contactID = AttributeValue("ContactID")  /* you have to set this first */
set @rows = LookupRows("Contacts","ContactID", @contactID)
set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
set @first = Field(@row,"first")

]%%
%%=ProperCase(@first)=%%
```

I have more lookup examples [here on my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an additional step if you're going to use LookupRows().

LookupRows() will retrieve your rowset. 
Row() will target the row. 
Field() will retrieve the value in column, w/in that row.

Adding to your code...

```
...
set @rows = LookupRows("Contacts","FirstName", @first)
set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
Set @first = Field(@row,"FirstNameColumn")
]%%

%%=ProperCase(@first)=%%
```

However, what you're doing doesn't seem to make much sense. The code is matching first name to first name in order to retrieve first name.

Comment: Thanks!  I've tried this but getting an odd behavior.  The email validates, but when I try to do a live preview it says it can't generate it... which usually means there's an error... but it validates.  Any ideas?